# Apache Jena: Deleting all data in the model

Tags: java, jena

I am trying to remove all the data that I have entered into my model using the ClearModel() method in the following class.

```
    public class JenaDatabaseHelper {

private Model model;
private Dataset dataset;

public Model getJenaModel(){
    if(model!=null){
        return model;
    }
    else{
        String directory = "JenaDatabase" ;
        try{
            dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(directory);
            model = dataset.getNamedModel("DB");
            return model;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error when retrieving model: "+e.getMessage());
        }              
    }
    return null;
}

public void SaveAndCloseModel(){
    if(model!=null && dataset!=null){
        model.commit();
        model.close();
        dataset.close();
    }
}

public void ClearModel(){
    if(model!=null && dataset!=null){
        model.removeAll();
        SaveAndCloseModel();
    }
}
```

But when I restart the application and iterate through the statements, nothing has been removed.

Comment: `Model.removeAll()` and `Statement.remove()` are both extensively tested in the Jena unit tests, so they definitely work. We need more details of your exact setup to diagnose what your problem is. How do you know that there is still data in the model?

Comment: I have updated the question with the full class. I am using TDB to save the model, but shouldn't Model.removeAll() still work? I know the data remains there as when I restart the application (after using the ClearModel() method) and iterate through the statements nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that `ClearModel` will silently do nothing if `model` is null. You might want to put an else branch on that conditional to print a warning in that case. This could occur, for example, if you create a new `JenaDatabaseHelper` instance and don't call `getJenaModel()` to initialise the instance variables first.

In fact, given the risk of having uninitialised variables, personally I would put the functionality of `getJenaModel` into the constructor. Alternatively, you could evaluate them lazily by accessing the `model` through a getter method, which would first check that `model` has been initialised.

Comment: You were right, I thought it was a more complex problem, but I just overlooked the fact that the model was null. Thanks for the help :)